# Azure AD application using Azure DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cosmosdb

I'm in the need of creating an Azure AD application with DocumentDB. We need to provide the connection string of a DB server in AD application where User Cache information will be stored.

When I try replacing SQL Azure connection string with DocumentDB connection string, getting an error:

> "application's configuration file does not contain the required
>   providerName attribute.".

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking: You're trying to swap out which database is used for your user cache, just by replacing a connection string? So basically trying to use a document store in place of a SQL Server store? You should edit your question to be a bit more clear.

Comment: Yes. I'm swapping out from SQL Server to DocumentDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply swap the connection string and expect your application to start using DocumentDB instead of SQL Server.  In your application, you are likely using the Entity Framework libraries, ADO.NET, or some other library that is specifically looking for a SQL Server connection string.  Furthermore, your code has dependencies on those libraries.

To make the switch from SQL Server to DocumentDB, you will need to pull in the DocumentDB client libraries.  Then, refactor code as needed to use the new libraries.

An example of a simple ASP.NET MVC application using DocumentDB is available [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/documentdb-dotnet-todo-app/).